# RichTextBox and underline color

Tags: winforms, colors, pinvoke, richtextbox, underline

Is there any way to change the color of an underline in a `RichTextBox`?
I've tried [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803184227/http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/188.aspx) but it doesn't seem to work. Anybody know where did those enum values came from? Didn't see any documentation for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The enum values are the standard windows values when passing messages to controls. One thing that the article doesn't mention, is that you need to have a selected text in the `RichTextBox` in order to apply formatting to it, so maybe that's what is missing.

Comment: I have selected text in the RichTextBox.